# How to make footer row visible false during row editing and visible true on when i cancel or save the record in Gridview

Tags: .net, gridview

How to make **footer row** visible *false* during row editing and visible *true* on when i cancel or save the record in **Gridview**, c#?? Initially i have set the gridview showfooter="true"

Answer (score 0):

In row editing  set :

```
GridID.FooterRow.Visible = false;
```

And in Cancel Or Save:

```
GridID.FooterRow.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Sry this didnt work  But i tried with 
*** Gridview1.ShowFooter = false;*** in edit event and vice versa. And this worked. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Use PreRender Event of GridView

```
protected void gvPrerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if( Gridview1.EditIndex!=-1 )
            Gridview1.FooterRow.Visible = false;
           else
               Gridview1.FooterRow.Visible = true;
        }
```